# Como passar variável do python para uma Query sql?

Tags: python, sql, query, mysqli, variáveis

Estou utilizando o MySQL como banco de dados. Queria conseguir passar o valor de uma variável do python como parâmetro nessa query.

Ex:

```
cursor = connection.cursor()

variavel_nome_cliente = input('Digite aqui o nome do cliente: ')

query = ('INSERT INTO tabela_ficticia(coluna_nomes) VALUES (variavel_nome_cliente)')

cursor.execute(query)
```

Já tentei de todas as formas, mas não estou conseguindo pegar o valor que está dentro da variável python e passar ela na query que faço em SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar as fstrings do Python e concatenar a variável na string da query

```
query = (f'INSERT INTO tabela_ficticia(coluna_nomes) VALUES ({variavel_nome_cliente})')
```

Perceba que a variável fica entre chaves `{ }` e tem um `f` antes das aspas

Fonte: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498

Comment: Acho que eu consegui. Fiz assim:


variavel_nome_cliente = input('Digite aqui o nome do cliente: ')

query = ('INSERT INTO tabela_ficticia(coluna_nomes) VALUES ({})').format(variavel_nome_cliente)

cursor.execute(query)

Comment: Neste caso isso faz a mesma coisa que escrevi na resposta. No link da fonte tem um comparativo do format e f-strings (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#differences-between-f-string-and-str-format-expressions). Na minha opinião seria mais fácil de entender a query se as f-strings fossem utilizadas

Answer (score 0):

Acho que eu consegui. Fiz assim:

```
variavel_nome_cliente = input('Digite aqui o nome do cliente: ') 

query = ('INSERT INTO tabela_ficticia(coluna_nomes) VALUES ({})').format(variavel_nome_cliente) 

cursor.execute(query)
```